# Image files as inputs with AWS Elastic Transcoder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ffmpeg, amazon-elastic-transcoder

Here's my situation. I've been working on building a service at work that takes dynamically generated images and outputs animations as mp4 or gif. The user has the options of setting dimensions, time for each frame, etc.

I have this working currently with ffmpeg. It works ok, but is difficult (and potentially expensive) to scale due largely to the cpu/memory requirements that ffmpeg needs.

I just spent some time experimenting with AWS's Elastic Transcoder. It doesn't seem to like static image files (jpg, png) as source material in jobs. The file types aren't listed under the available Preset options either.

I'm sure that I could adapt the existing architecture to save the static images as video files (sound isn't needed) and upload those. That will still require ffmpeg to be in the pipeline though.

Are there any other AWS services that might work with my needs and allow the use of Elastic Transcoder?